# Saving data to a client-side file

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-io, client-side

I am writing a web application and I am getting some data from a server using jQuery.

I want to save the data in a file on client-side and I tried this using the plugin
JQuery.tWFile.js, but get the following exception

> Error: A script from `http://localhost` was denied UniversalXPConnect privileges

How can I fix this? Are there any other better possibilities to save the data that I get from a server in a client-side file?

Comment: let user download that file. =)

Answer (score 0):

how about using localStorage? [link to storage possibilities at mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage)

EDIT: I think it has lesser limitations, is also bound to the current domain and exists across browser sessions... only clearing the cache would reset it afaik

Comment: `localStorage` is usually [limited to several megabytes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2989317/975097), but it's possible to store larger amounts of data using the [IndexedDB API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API).

Answer (score 0):

The script is failing because your Uri is localhost, this may be a loopback IP... but to your browser it's still a web site. Writing local files is only allowed when browsing a local file using a file:// Uri.

If you can't use a file:// Uri, then you'll have to settle for cookies or localStorage.

Answer (score -1):

It should work if you use `file:///path/to/file.html`